# Does having many models yield complex second-order theories?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, computability, second-order-logic

*Below, $T$ is a complete **first-order** theory in a finite language with no finite models.*

*Also [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369026/number-of-models-vs-complexity-for-sol-theories).*

---

### Question

Suppose $T$ has continuum-many countable models. We define two sets of Turing degrees associated to $T$ via second-order logic:

- $SecTh(T)$ is the set of Turing degrees of second-order theories of models of $T$.
- $SecTh_0(T)$ is the set of Turing degrees of second-order theories of *countable* models of $T$.

I'm interested in how simple these sets can be. Specifically:

> Is there a $T$ such that $SecTh(T)$ is not cofinal in the Turing degrees? If not, what about $SecTh_0(T)$?

Recall that $X$ is cofinal in the Turing degrees if every Turing degree is below some element of $X$.

---

### Some comments

- Assuming $V=L$, the answer is negative for $SecTh_0$ (and hence $SecTh$ a fortiori). The key point is that  under $V=L$ the set of [pointwise-definable](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597) levels of $L$ is unbounded in $\omega_1$. Given a countable $\mathcal{A}\models T$, let $\alpha_\mathcal{A}$ be the least index of a pointwise-definable level of $L$ containing an isomorphic copy of $\mathcal{A}$. The second-order theory of $\mathcal{A}$ computes $Th(L_\alpha)$, which in turn computes every real in $L_\alpha$ by pointwise definability. Now simply use the fact that $\{\alpha_\mathcal{A}:\mathcal{A}\models T\}$ is unbounded in $\omega_1$. (Note that this is a "naive" version of the idea behind [mastercodes](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1183740554).)
- I don't actually see an immediate argument that $SecTh(T)$ need be uncountable! A priori, $Th_2(\mathcal{A})$ may not be enough to build a concrete copy of $\mathcal{A}$ in any sense that I can see. It is *consistent* that $SecTh_0(T)$ (and hence $SecTh(T)$) is always uncountable, since it's consistent that no two countable structures are second-order elementarily equivalent (see Marek's theorem mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/161694/8133)), but that's the best I know.
- Under sufficiently strong large cardinal hypotheses, $SecTh_0(T)$ is subject to [Martin's Cone Theorem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/46145/52244), and hence for an affirmative answer for the second question it would be enough to find a $T$ such that $SecTh_0(T)$ does not contain an upper cone. Under such hypotheses *and* replacing $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with $\mathsf{ZF}$ + Turing Determinacy the same would hold for $SecTh(T)$, but I don't immediately see how to get this stronger result without determinacy.

Comment: The dead link to the paper on mastercodes used to go to this paper: Harold T. Hodes, *[Jumping Through the Transfinite: The Master Code Hierarchy of Turing Degrees](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=hodes+jumping+through+transfinite),* The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 45, No. 2 (Jun., 1980), pp. 204-220; [DOI: 10.2307/2273183](https://doi.org/10.2307/2273183), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273183)